# Shell repeat execute ssh and scp command

Tags: bash, shell

I have two line need to repeat doing in for loop

```
ssh tam@192.168.174.43 mkdir -p $location
scp -r $i tam@192.168.174.43:$location
```

but each time it need to input password, how can i change code then just need input one time or more fast way

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` possible?

Comment: how can i change those two line using rsync ?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

Comment: And then more geekstuff: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You can use public/private key generation method using ssh-keygen (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)
And then use the below script.

```
for VARIABLE in dir1 dir2 dir3
do
ssh tam@192.168.174.43 mkdir -p $location
scp -r $i tam@192.168.174.43:$location
done
```

Alternative solution :
You can use [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)

```
for VARIABLE in dir1 dir2 dir3
do
ssh tam@192.168.174.43 mkdir -p $location sshpass -p '<password>' <command>
scp -r $i tam@192.168.174.43:$location sshpass -p '<password>' <command>
done
```

Comment: Please note that the 1st method above is **highly** preferable (or, even, the only you should use) : the 2nd one can make the password appear to anyone on the system (via 'ps'). And the first one should have the private key only be readable by the user and no others should be able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

While public/private keys is the easiest option, without need to change the existing script, there is another option, of using [`sshfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs). sshfs may not be installed by default.

With this approach, you basically `mount` the remote file system to a local directory, over ssh protocol. Then you can simply use commands like mkdir / cp etc.

**NOTE**: These command are from YOUR system & not from REMOTE system.

Mounting over ssh is a one time job, which will require your manual intervention. Do this before running the script.
e.g. for your case:

```
mkdir /tmp/tam_192.168.174.43
sshfs tam@192.168.174.43:/ /tmp/tam_192.168.174.43
tam@192.168.174.43's password: <ENTER PASSWORD HERE>
```

& then, in your script, use simple commands like:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/tam_192.168.174.43/$location
cp -r $i /tmp/tam_192.168.174.43/$location
```

& to unmount:

```
fusermount -u /tmp/tam_192.168.174.43
```